# SQLite, getting last item in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I need some help with using the database that I created. I need to access the last item in the database. This is my code that gets a single item. How can I change it to only get the last?

```
// Getting single user
User getuser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, 
            KEY_GOAL, KEY_BMI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()!=0){
          cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4), 
            cursor.getString(5), cursor.getFloat(6));
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the id uniquely identifies the user then you will be getting only one row as the result for the id you are passing so you dont have to worry about it is the last or first in the database.  if it is just that you want the last row in your database then you dont have to pass an id you can do a select * and after retrieving move the cursor to last ie cursor.moveToLast().

Do this if you just want the last row

```
User getuser() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


  Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, 
        KEY_GOAL, KEY_BMI }, null,
        null, null, null, null, null);

  if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()!=0){
      cursor.moveToLast();
  }

  User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4), 
        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getFloat(6));
  return user;
}
```

and your call can be like this

```
User currentUser = db.getUser();
```

If you are passing an id to get a user details an the id uniquely identifies the user then what you have done will work

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, 
        KEY_GOAL, KEY_BMI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, KEY_ID + " DESC", "LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: So if I wanted to make a current user the last user of the database, How would I assign it to a variable (of type user)?  currentUser = db.getuser(id);

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for `cursor.moveToLast()`? This will move the cursor to the last record selected from your query. You can then get the fields values as usual using `cursor.getString(n)` etc.

Comment: how do I set it to a variable? say currentUser = get the last id in the table. thanks

Comment: I have an object called user and I would like to access a row from the database like db.getUser(last id);

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change a little in your code,

```
// Getting single user
User getuser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, 
            KEY_GOAL, KEY_BMI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()!=0){
          cursor.moveToLast();                     // Change here
    }

    User user = new User(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4), 
            cursor.getString(5), cursor.getFloat(6));
    return user;
}
```

Comment: and what do i pass as the id parameter when i am getting the user?

Comment: for example, when i am setting the cuurent user: currentUser = db.getUser(id). Since I am getting that last item there is no need to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Cursor c = db.rawquery("Select *from tablename");
c.movetoLast();
```

and if you want to get the data from last to first use this codes:

```
Cursor c = db.rawquery("Select *from tablename");
c.movetoLast();
int count = c.getCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
c.movetoPrevious();
}
```