# How to get the last rowid from a table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The Cursor is everytime -1

Before i have

`db.getWritableDatabase`

`TABLE_NAME_NOTES` is in every three places notes

```
public String addNote(){
    String id = "";

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("Date","date");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME_NOTES, null, values);

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select last_insert_rowid() as fullname from " + TABLE_NAME_NOTES, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            id = cursor.getString(0);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME_NOTES, null);
    if(cursor.moveToLast()){
        long long_id = cursor.getInt(0);/
        id = Long.toString(long_id);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;
}
```

How can i get the last id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite, getting last item in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600581/sqlite-getting-last-item-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the app from the device/emulator and rerun.
This is necessary for the database to be deleted and recreated so any new columns you have defined will exist in the table.
Every time you define a new column in code does not automatically get created in the table.
The method [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues)) returns the `rowid` of the row that you insert or -1 if the insert was unsuccesfull:

```
long lastInsertedId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_NOTES, null, values);
```

Comment: It's really -1. Why if i don't have an error in the insert-line? There are no Not-Null Fields in the table

Comment: Insert() does not throw errors. Try `insertOrThrow()` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: table notes has no column named Date. But there is a column named Date     private static final String TABLE_NOTES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
              + TABLE_NAME_NOTES
            + " (_id"
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "ID_Server TEXT(10),"
            + "Titel TEXT(60),"
            + "Beschreibung TEXT(5000),"
            + "Date TEXT(19))";

Comment: in mysql there is also an issue     INSERT INTO `notes`(`Date`) VALUES (`date2`)


#1054 - Unknown column 'date2' in field list      how can that be?

Comment: What is it?SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: I dropped the table. This will also work. But best answer by far. It's SQLite. I just tested in mysql. But there i don't know why it behaves like this. This question is solved. Thanks.

Comment: In MySql you can't insert a value like 'Date' in a column with data type Date. In SQLite you can since everything is TEXT.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.